# AutocompleteTextView click listener called twice

Tags: java, android, dropdown, onclicklistener, autocompletetextview

I've this layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_birthdate"
    style="@style/ExposedDropDownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/birthdate">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete_birthdate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:editable="false" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

With this style:

```
<!-- ExposedDropdownMenu -->
<style name="ExposedDropDownMenu" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_layout_outlined_box_stroke</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/green_2</item>
</style>
```

I've tried to set a click listener on the autocomplete text view:

```
autoComplete.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    // This is called twice when i click the autocomplete textview
});
```

The listener is called twice...why? How can i solve this?

EDIT: removing the style, the first click (gaining the focus) is ignored, than the second click is called correctly once, but I lose the "ripple" background effect anyway.

Comment: Try .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});

Comment: Since I can't comment, I'll have to ask in an answer:
did u make sure, that the adding of the eventlistener doesnt happen twice?

Comment: @AlessandroVerona that's exactly what I'm doing...

Comment: I'm sure I'm setting it only once.

Comment: @Jumpa have you tried to investigate such behaviour with breakpoint?

Comment: @Vault23 I'll try that...I was hoping that was a common problem, I'm not really happy to debug the android sdk code every time.

Comment: @Jumpa take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923663/autocompletetextview-setonitemselectedlistener-not-working)

Comment: @Vault23 That's not about the click on the dropdown item, i'm trying to show a dialog when clicking on the autocompletetextview itself.

Comment: Can you share any GitHub link for your source code, please?

Comment: @Jumpa ,override onTouchEvent inside  AutoCompleteTextView and return true inside the function to consume the touch event

Comment: What do you mean? "The listener is called twice"

Comment: Please attach your full code

Comment: I test your code... it's correctly working without any bug ..change your parent style and test again

Answer (score 1):

You can try the **setOnTouchListener** instead, it's called just once and keeps the ripple as well.

```
autocomplete_birthdate.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
    if (motionEvent.action == ACTION_UP) {
        // Some code
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try the below example.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Click Event"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/til_selector"
            app:boxStrokeErrorColor="@color/colorRed_700"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/etClickEvent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                **android:focusableInTouchMode="false"** />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Now set Programmatically

```
etClickEvent.inputType = 0
etClickEvent.setOnClickListener{
//PUT YOUR OWN 
}
```

This is working fine for me.