# Setting auto-complete timeout for a geocoding results

Tags: android, autocomplete, timeout, geocoding

What is the best way to manage to handle the typing-timeout?

I tried the code like this (inspired by the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142885/geocoder-autocomplete-in-android)):

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
//...
    Message msg = Message.obtain(messageHandler, MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED, arg0.toString());
    messageHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 1000 );
//...
}
```

but in the logs I can see that the geocoder gets invoked upon each key-press, no matter how fast I type. I'd like to have the same behaviour like Javascript's setTimeout(...) function has.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cancel the previous messages sent to the handler when a new key is pressed:

```
Message msg = Message.obtain(messageHandler, MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED, arg0.toString());
messageHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED);
messageHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 1000 );
```